# javascript constant in an html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript constant and I was wondering if and how I can get that constant in an input form.  For example.

```
<input form="POST" action="INSERT_API_CONSTANT_HERE/myroute" />
```

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like that.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any server-side technology? It seems to be better suited for that

Comment: javascript doesn't have constant

Comment: @Wagner while this is true, it's possible to emulate this by using ES5 getters and setters. The final behavior is almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your HTML tag is wrong. `<form>` is a different tag from `<input>`, so to be a form, it should be:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="{{api}}/myroute">
    <input type="text" value="this is an input" />
</form>
```

I also provided an `<input>` tag to you note the difference, now let's go to changing form action dynamically via javascript with JQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

//your "constant"
var MY_CONSTANT = "some_value";

//option A: to set action parameter, replace"{{api}}" text to your "constant" value
var originalAction = $("#myForm").attr("action");
$("#myForm").attr("action" , originalAction.replace("{{api}}", MY_CONSTANT));

//option B: you could leave form action empty in HTML and write everythig here via javascript
$("myForm").attr("action" ,MY_CONSTANT + "/myroute" );

</script>
```

Both options A and B works, but I don't think replacing a text for another the best solution, I prefer option B in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("form").attr("action", $("form").attr("action")
         .replace(/INSERT_API_CONSTANT_HERE/g, APIConstant))
```